# Do something whenever a new document is added to collection

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Listening for updates to a collection in angularfire2 is easy enough. I want to **also run a function** whenever the new item is added to (or removed from) the collection. Here's some sample code::

```
let path = 'doc1/' + doc2 + '/doc3/';

this.varCollection = this.afs.collection(path);
this.var = this.varCollection.valueChanges();          //Do something here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueChanges()` returns an Observable so you can subscribe it as so:

```
this.subscription = this.varCollection.valueChanges().subscribe((val) => {
  this.var = val;  
  runSomeFunc();
})
```

In case you use an `async` pipe in your template or just want to keep Observable as it is, try to `.map()` it and then return:

```
this.var = this.varCollection.valueChanges().map(_ => {console.log('value changed'); return _});
```

If you need document's metadata, can use `snapshotChanges()`:

```
this.subscription = this.varCollection.snapshotChanges().subscribe( //do something )
```